# How to Create a Multiple People Picker field in a HTML form using JQuery

Tags: rest, jquery, people-picker, jquery-ui

I want to create a People picker field in a HTML Form, which should accepts multiple people names, with comma or semicolon separated,

Usually I create a input text field in the HTML form and then using JQuery I convert it to a people picker

Here is the code I have used for single people picker:

```
     $("#name").autocomplete({
         source: search,
         minLength: 1
     });
```

in the same way I want to know how to add multiple people picker.

Also I want to know how to save them in the list using REST API.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Client Side people picker in your custom HTML form.

Check below official documentation by Microsoft for same (Check for JavaScript code):

[Use the client-side People Picker control in SharePoint-hosted SharePoint Add-ins](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-the-client-side-people-picker-control-in-sharepoint-hosted-sharepoint-add-in).

Also check below article for Step by Step guide:

[Client Side People Picker In SharePoint 2013](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/client-side-people-picker-in-sharepoint-2013).

**To Save Multiple Users in Person or Group field using REST API:**

First of all you have to **Allow multiple selections** in Person or Group(Say `AssignedTo`) column.

[image]

To add/update multi valued Person or Group column, you have to specify the `ID`'s of the Persons or Groups like

```
var data = {
    __metadata: { "type": "SP.Data.TestListItem" },
    Title: "Some title",
    AssignedToId: { 'results': [11,22] } 
}
```

You will find more in this [CRUD Operation to List Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)

Comment: Hi @Jegan, Does this answers your question? Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you so that it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. Also it removes the question from "Unanswered questions" list.